# MySQL Update with Inner Join with Like

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

Can someone tell me why this query will not work?  I have 20k rows to update.  The select query returns the rows but the Update query will not run.

UPDATE QUERY

```
UPDATE TEST_shoe_data t
INNER JOIN shoe_data_temp s 
ON t.sku = s.sku 
SET t.thumbnail = s.thumbnail 
WHERE t.thumbnail like '%4x.jpg%'
```

SELECT QUERY

```
select count(*)
from TEST_shoe_data
where thumbnail like '%4x.jpg%'
```

Comment: the second query you show doesn't really help - how many records result from the join of the two tables?  as you can see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4cee/1),  your syntax is fine, so it must be your data

Comment: When you say the `UPDATE` query does not run, do you mean you get an error or just nothing happens?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I imagine the problem is with the `join`...

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine. It's likely that your data isn't what you think it is.

As you can see in this [demo fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4cee/1), your query syntax is fine, and it does exactly what it says it will.

This means your join conditions are probably wrong.

does:

```
select count(*) from test_shoe_data t inner join shoe_data_temp s on t.sku = s.sku
```

return a positive count?

what about:

```
select count(*) from test_shoe_data t inner join shoe_data_temp s on t.sku = s.sku where t.thumbnail like '%4x.jpg%'
```

Or are there even any rows that match the where condition?

```
select count(*) from test_shoe_data where thumbnail like '%4x.jpg%'
```

Comment: Of the queries above the first returns 71k records.  The second one returns 0 records.  The third returns 21k records.  Adding the where/like statement makes it return 0 records.  Its very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Your query works. What is your problem?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6965f/1

```
UPDATE TEST_shoe_data t
INNER JOIN shoe_data_temp s 
ON t.sku = s.sku 
SET t.thumbnail = s.thumbnail 
WHERE t.thumbnail like '%4x.jpg%'
```